# Why I'm not getting data from the job page on Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get job description and company name from the Job page but I'm not receiving it and I couldn't find out issue as well. Cause seems everything is ok to me. So Please help me, Why I'm not getting Data from Job Page?

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class IndeedSpider(Spider):
    name = 'indeed'
    allowed_domains = ['indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Russian&fromage=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "row result")]')
        for job in jobs:
            job_title = job.xpath('.//*[@class="title"]//a/@title').extract_first()
            job_location = job.xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "location")]/text()').extract_first()
            job_link = job.xpath('.//*[@class="title"]//a/@href').extract_first()
            absulate_job_link = response.urljoin(job_link)
            print(absulate_job_link)

            yield Request(url=absulate_job_link,
                          callback=self.parse_jobpage,
                          meta={
                              "Job Title": job_title,
                              "Location": job_location,
                              "Job Link": absulate_job_link
                            })



    def parse_jobpage(self, response):
        job_title = response.meta.get('Job Title')
        job_location = response.meta.get('Location')
        absulate_job_link = response.meta.get('Job Link')

        job_description = "".join(line for line in response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDescriptionText"]//text()').extract())

        company = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "icl-u-lg-mr--sm")]//text()').extract_first()

        yield {
            "Job Title": job_title,
            "Location": job_location,
            "Job Link": absulate_job_link,
            "Job Description": job_description,
            "Company": company
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `allowed_domains` does not match the urls you're trying to parse.
This causes your first request to be filtered as offsite, and no further requests are made.

Changing your `allowed_domains` to `['indeed.co.uk']` should fix the problem.